# GWT - how to implement RequestContext methods outside an @Entity-annotated class?

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory, gwt-2.4

Is it possible to implement `RequestContext` methods outside an @Entity-annotated class?

```
@Entity
class TheEntity {
  public static TheEntity theMethod() { ... } // don't want it here
}

@Service(TheEntity.class)
interface TheEntityRequest extends RequestContext {
  Request<TheEntity> theMethod(); // this one
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is mentioned in the official [GWT documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#locators), though it's not very detailed.

I've found of great help this [blog post](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/using-gwt-requestfactory-with-objectify/) by David Chandler.

Some pointers:
(example links are from the project discussed in the blog post)

**Entity locator methods** (`find`, `create`, `getId`, `getVersion`) can be moved in a generic Locator class ([example](http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/turbomanage/listwidget/server/locator/ObjectifyLocator.java)). For this to work your entities must extend a BasicEntity class that has the `getId` and `getVersion` methods. Then on the client you would specify the locator like this:

```
@ProxyFor(value = MyEntity.class, locator = GenericLocator.class)
public interface MyEntityProxy extends EntityProxy {
...
}
```

**Data access methods** can be moved in a service. You can have a generic service ([example](http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/turbomanage/listwidget/server/service/ObjectifyDao.java)), and then extend it for each entity to provide specific methods ([example](http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/turbomanage/listwidget/server/service/NamedListDao.java)).

On the client you define your service like this:

```
// MyEntityDao is your server service for MyEntity
@Service(value = MyEntityDao.class, locator = MyServiceLocator.class) 
interface MyEntityRequestContext extends RequestContext { 
Request<List<MyEntityProxy>> listAll();
Request<Void> save(MyEntityProxy entity);
... 
}
```

Note the need for a service locator also. It can be as simple as [this](http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/turbomanage/listwidget/server/locator/DaoServiceLocator.java).

Comment: Could you please provide a short example?